# How to properly display a vCard or vCal

Tags: php, jquery, vcf-vcard, vcal

Via a mobile App my users can send a reference object with their data to our server. This is either a calander event or a contact. The format used is vCal or vCard.

On my website I would like to display the reference object along with the data. Idealy a icon which on hover or click displays the vCard / vCal with a the possibility to save it.
This doensn't have to be with ajax.
My site uses jquery and has to be able to work in IE7 and higher.

I've found quite bunch of examples (mostly CV or gallery type stuff) in a range of technology's (microformats and so on). I'm looking for a more simple example.

What would be a good plugin or sollution for this?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hCard microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) to mark up the vCard data on your site, e.g.

```
<div class="vcard">
    <address class="adr author">
        <span class="type hide">work</span>
        <span class="fn">John Doe</span>
        <span class="role">Webdeveloper</span>
        <span class="street-address">Fooway 1</span>
        <span class="postal-code">1234 </span> <span class="locality">N.Y.</span>
        <span class="hide country-name">USA</span>
    </address>
    <div>
        <span class="tel">
            <span class="type">Tel</span>
            <span class="value">0800-1234567</span>
        </span>
        <span class="tel">
            <span class="type">Fax</span>
            <span class="value">0800-7654321</span>
        </span>
        <a class="email" href="mailto:jd@example.com">Mail Me</a>
        <span class="url">http://www.example.com</span>
    </div>
    <div class="hcard-export">
    <a href="http://h2vx.com/vcf/http://www.stb-rueter.de/">
        <img src="/images//icons/hcard.png" alt="hCard Microformat" />
        <span>Download vCard</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Then add a link to convert that via http://h2vx.com/vcf. The service will parse the URL you tell it to for any hCards on the site, convert them to a vCard and offer that for download then.

Comment: @Jeroen the structure above is more or less arbitrary. It's trivial to create a function which returns this html. Just put the code in a function accepting the person's data and replace it inside.

Comment: @Jeroes you didnt upvote/accept my answer, so I assume it is not helpful to you. Can you please update your question to point out what you are looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Had more urgent matters. I didn't fully review your link, yet. But I'm looking for something (like many jQuery features) enhances a div or something similar that contains the vCard code.

Comment: @Jeroen well, it's not jQuery. It's just a link to a service. You markup the contact data with the hCard microformat and then tell h2vx to extract and convert this hCard to a downloadable vCard.